# How is the hash used to find unique items

Tags: perl

I have seen one easy program. Well, the hole program i have understand except one thing and that is how Hash is working here :

Program ->Extracting Unique Elements from a List

```
@list = (20,30,40,60,40,20,30,2);
@uniq = ();
%seen = ();
foreach $item (@list) {
    unless ($seen{$item}) 
    {
        # if we get here, we have not seen it before
        push(@uniq, $item);
        $seen{$item}++;

    }
    print %seen;
    print"\n";
}
```

My question is how hash is comparing from its exiting value to current value i.e how it is checking weather that value is already there or not .If I m printing the %seen i am getting some value.how those values are coming ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it makes it clearer for your, change

```
if (!$seen{$item}) { $seen{$item}++; ... }
```

to

```
if (!exists($seen{$item})) { $seen{$item} = 1; ... }
```

The first time you encounter a particular item, it doesn't exist as a key in the hash, so the `if` is entered. The body of the `if` creates a key in the hash equal to the item.

The second (and third and ...) time you encounter a particular item, it exists as a key in the hash, so the `if` is not entered.

---

By the way,

```
if (!$seen{$item}) { $seen{$item}++; ... }
```

can be shortened to

```
if (!$seen{$item}++) { ... }
```

And

```
my @uniq;
for my $item (@list) {
    push @uniq, $item if ...;
}
```

can be shortened to

```
my @uniq = grep ..., @list;
```

So the whole thing can be written as

```
my @list = (20,30,40,60,40,20,30,2);
my %seen;
my @uniq = grep !$seen{$_}++, @list;
```

Comment: @user1202644, If this answers your question, please close it by checking the mark next to the best answer. If not, let us know what's missing. Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: @ ikegami , but where can i find "best answer"? sorry but i could not find it :(

Comment: @user1202644, I meant mine, or perreal's, or ... If those answers aren't good enough, let us know what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

The check `unless ($seen{$item})` probes the hash table for the key `$item`. If the key is seen, the test will fail because `$seen{$item}` will be defined and non-zero.

If there is no entry in the hash-table:

```
push(@uniq, $item);   # store this item
$seen{$item}++;       # and increment the value for this key in the hash table
```

An undefined value is considered to be `0`, so the statement `$seen{$item}++` makes its value 1 (you might as well write this as `$seen{$item} = 1`.

If the item is encountered again in the list, the `unless ($seen{$item})` will not succeed, so the it will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks Perreal for such a nice explanation !!

Answer (score 0):

`$seen{$item}` will either be undefined or a number.

`$seen{$item}++;` will make it a number.