# check for md5sum to identify duplicate files in perl

Tags: perl, md5sum

How can I check for duplicate files using md5sum in perl in an if statement?

I am looking for a line of code that does this:

```
if { (md5 of new file matches any of the md5sum values of already parsed files)
print "duplicate found"
} else { new file and add md5sum to a list for check)
print "new file"
}
```

Comment: You should look at [`Digest::MD5`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html). It shows an example of how to compute the hashsum of a file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the hash used to find unique items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653254/how-is-the-hash-used-to-find-unique-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally the idiomatic way of performing this operation is to use a hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.018;

my %seen;

for my $string (qw/ one two three four one five six four seven two one /) {
    if ( $seen{$string} ) {
        say "saw $string";
    }
    else {
        $seen{$string}++;
        say "new $string";
    }
}
```

[How is the hash used to find unique items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653254/how-is-the-hash-used-to-find-unique-items/11653437#11653437) goes into more detail.

As mentioned in comment, you'd use a library like [Digest::MD5](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html) to generate the MD5 strings for the files. Hooking the two together is left an an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to calculate a hash-code for each file you encounter. In pseudo-code:

```
my %md5_to_file;

for every file
    push @{ $md5_to_file{ md5 of file } }, file
```

Then, any value in the `%md5_to_file` mapping with cardinality > 1 points to possible duplicates. You can then do further checks to ascertain whether you have collisions or genuine duplicates.

See also [DFW Perl Mongers ONLINE Hackathon Smackdown - Results, Awards, And Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvqqRFGMZS0) .